# Adding 2 or more numbers in the same cell in excel

Tags: excel-formula, formula

In numerology you add, for example, the numbers for your year of birth; let's assume 1945. When these digits are added together they total 19 (1+9+4+5). They must then be added again to come up with a single number, in this instance 10 then 1. Could you please provide a formula for this?

Comment: Provide us some code that you have tried with and we'll show you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Share the formula you already tried so that we can help you in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your VBA file (hit Alt-F11) will give you a function called "totalString".

The sum can then be calculated using `=totalString(A1)`, where `A1` is the cell containing your number, eg `1945`, or directly using (you guessed it...) `=totalString(1945)`

```
Function totalString(ByVal numberString As Integer) As Integer
    Dim length As Integer
    length = LEN(numberString)
    Dim sum As Integer
    sum = 0

    For i=1 To length
        sum = sum + mid(numberString, i, 1)
    Next i
```

EDIT: Instead of this next section, you could use the 3rd code block (at the bottom of the post) to specify only certain values to add.

```
    Dim l2 As Integer
    l2 = LEN(sum)
    If l2 <> 1 Then
        totalString = totalString(sum)
    Else
        totalString = sum
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

3rd block (alternative ending...)

```
    If sum > 11 Then
        totalString = totalString(sum)
    Else
        totalString = sum
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

The function calculates the length of the number you give it, and then gets adds the value of each number. It checks to see if the length of the sum is 1, and if not, recursively calls the function.